# Online JSON Genetator Contains Page for flatList

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

im wanna implement react native load More and refreshing, but i need to online jason Generator that contains page number (the json data in multiple pages)

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON placeholder with pagination
with this link: http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?_start=5&_limit=10

just need to change argument `_start` and `_limit` so you can get json with paging.

Example json get from jsonplaceholder.typicode.com

```
[
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 6,
    "title": "dolorem eum magni eos aperiam quia",
    "body": "ut aspernatur corporis harum nihil quis provident sequi\nmollitia nobis aliquid molestiae\nperspiciatis et ea nemo ab reprehenderit accusantium quas\nvoluptate dolores velit et doloremque molestiae"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 7,
    "title": "magnam facilis autem",
    "body": "dolore placeat quibusdam ea quo vitae\nmagni quis enim qui quis quo nemo aut saepe\nquidem repellat excepturi ut quia\nsunt ut sequi eos ea sed quas"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 8,
    "title": "dolorem dolore est ipsam",
    "body": "dignissimos aperiam dolorem qui eum\nfacilis quibusdam animi sint suscipit qui sint possimus cum\nquaerat magni maiores excepturi\nipsam ut commodi dolor voluptatum modi aut vitae"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 9,
    "title": "nesciunt iure omnis dolorem tempora et accusantium",
    "body": "consectetur animi nesciunt iure dolore\nenim quia ad\nveniam autem ut quam aut nobis\net est aut quod aut provident voluptas autem voluptas"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 10,
    "title": "optio molestias id quia eum",
    "body": "quo et expedita modi cum officia vel magni\ndoloribus qui repudiandae\nvero nisi sit\nquos veniam quod sed accusamus veritatis error"
  }
]
```

Comment: tnx. but how change the arguments? and i have to install it?

Comment: change in URL, just like `fetch(`http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?_start=${start}&_limit=${limit}`)`

Comment: You don't have to install. You just need make HTTP GET request to that url so you can get json, simulate like you call from app to api

Comment: and will using 'userId' instead of pages?

Comment: maybe, this placeholder need base on userId to count page.

Comment: if my answer correct what you need please mark as correct and upvote. thanks

Comment: sorry but i cant use userird as page number

Comment: I just check all jsonplaceholder apis, doesn't have any have page number. IF you want to determine which page is show I suggest you use `id` (like"id": 10 ) get current page by `id/countPerPage` , `countPerPage` is const/variable you define before